# Reactjs - Full image not appearing

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm having troubles with getting my full image to appear and I was wondering what's wrong with my current approach?

The image that I'm trying to set to full-size is [image]

However, this is what is rendering[image]

I'm setting my height to 100% so I'm not sure why it's only appearing with the text :-(

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  height:100%;
  width:100%; 
}

body, html {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.bg { 
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("./../../images/City.png");

    /* Full height */
     height: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return <div className="App">
         <div className="bg">
            hello world
         </div>
     </div>;
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: What it looks like after I tried one of the demos from the replies

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide CSS for `.App`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to bg div CSS:

```
.bg{
min-height: 600px; /*For example*/
}
```

because the bg div takes the height of its content if min-height is not specified.

Another solution is to put the image in a normal image element and make the bg div absolute over it.

For example (using inline CSS for explanation )

```
<div class="App" style="position:relative;width:100%;">
    <img src="the path" style="width:100%; height:auto;" />
    <div class="bg" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;"
         hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the first method, is there a way to set `min-height` to be 100%? It does fix my problem and help show the image but I'd like to be able to resize it based on browser size as well

Comment: For some reason, setting `min-height: 100%;` displays the image as the one above (where it only shows a small piece of the image). If I use a number value, it'll show the image

Comment: @Tim try to use min-width:100% as well. Note: If you can put your example on a https://jsfiddle.net/ or live demo it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the CSS of your `.App`, and will also depend of the DOM/HTML structure that wraps/contains the `div` where your city background image is displayed.

Consider updating the CSS for `.App` as follows:

```
.App {
  display:flex; 
  height:100%;
  width:100%; 
}
```

You may also need to ensure that the actual `html` and `body` elements of your DOM are styled to cover your entire client view area in the browser (depending on your website's structure):

```
html, body {
  display:flex;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

For a full working demo, [please see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tq5cs1d/3/). Hope this helps!

Note, you shouldn't copy the HTML from this jsFiddle directly. JSX/React requires that you use the `className` attribute to specify a DOM element's `class`.

So:

```
<div class="App">
  <div class="bg">
    hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

should be updated to:

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="bg">
    hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

in your component's `render()` method.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to do the trick for me :-(. I've added my css for `app.js` so maybe this will make things a little bit easier?

Comment: I tried copying and pasting over the code from the demo and the image in the original post is what I see. Is it because I'm using React that it doesn't render the css correctly or something?

Comment: @Tim with react you'll need to make sure you use `className` rather than just `class` - be careful not to do a direct copy/paste from my jsFiddle. If you are copy/pasting, update `class` to `className` in the HTML - does that work for you?

Comment: I've been using `className` instead of `class` which makes me confused as to why it doesn't seem to be rendering the css :-(